# What does this notification badge in macOS Catalina System Preferences mean?

Tags: macos, notifications, system-preferences, macos-catalina

I just upgraded to macOS 10.15 Catalina, and now I have this **(1)** badge on my System Preferences dock icon.

[image: macOS Catalina dock with badge on System Preferences dock]

Here's my System Preferences:

[image: macOS Catalina System Preferences]

I don't see any badges on the preference pane icons, but I did click through to each of them and didn't see any obvious action items. I was signed in with my Apple ID previously, and signing out did not make the badge go away.

Comment: could it because you are not signed in to iCloud?

Comment: No, but clicking the sign in button did make it go away. I signed out again and the badge is gone. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Catalina and ran into this problem. To fix it, it went into System Preferences > AppleID (Top right hand corner) > the left panel, click on Overview > There, it should say you need to link your AppleID once you've done that, it will ask you to enable two factor authentication. Once I did that, the red badge for system preferences went away.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is essentially what I did, but instead of enabling 2FA I just signed back out.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I'm not signed into AppleID and do not plan to. I have one to purchase apps, but I don't want to be constantly nagged to start using iCloud, it's not going to happen. Nevertheless I've got the one-badge... any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Same problem here, never will use this service, all badge notifications are disabled but the badge is still there. Also it is not possible to remove the settings icon permanently from dock