# Catalina System Preferences shows update badge, but no updates are available

Tags: macos-catalina, software-update, system-preferences

I just upgraded to Catalina, and now my System Preferences icon in the Dock shows an update badge with an annoying little “1” in it:

[image: Dock with annoying badge]

So far, so similar to [this old question](https://superuser.com/questions/1491480). Unlike that question, though, when I open up System Preferences, the Software Update icon has the same update badge, so I can at least see where the Dock icon is getting its badge from:

[image: System Preferences with Software Update badge]

When I actually click on Software Update, though – surprise, surprise! – there are no updates available (last checked today at 9:43, which is ten minutes ago):

[image: No updates available!]

Update settings are set to be as automatic as possible:

[image: Advanced update settings]

The contents of `com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist` are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AutomaticCheckEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>AutomaticDownload</key>
    <true/>
    <key>AutomaticallyInstallMacOSUpdates</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ConfigDataInstall</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CriticalUpdateInstall</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LastAttemptBuildVersion</key>
    <string>10.15.4 (19E266)</string>
    <key>LastAttemptSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.15.4 (19E266)</string>
    <key>LastBackgroundSuccessfulDate</key>
    <date>2020-03-26T12:47:19Z</date>
    <key>LastFullSuccessfulDate</key>
    <date>2020-03-26T12:47:05Z</date>
    <key>LastRecommendedMajorOSBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.InstallAssistant.Catalina</string>
    <key>LastRecommendedUpdatesAvailable</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>LastResultCode</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>LastSessionSuccessful</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LastSuccessfulDate</key>
    <date>2020-03-26T12:47:05Z</date>
    <key>LastUpdatesAvailable</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>PrimaryLanguages</key>
    <array>
        <string>en-GB</string>
    </array>
    <key>RecommendedUpdates</key>
    <array/>
    <key>SkipLocalCDN</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(Note that `LastUpdatesAvailable` is 0, as you’d expect it to be.)

So why is the main screen in System Preferences convinced that there are updates available, even deluding my Dock icon into believing it too? Is there some preference file or cache somewhere that I can delete/flush to make System Preferences reevaluate this existential crisis it seems to be going through?

Comment: What do you see in the Advanced window? Is your Mac set to automatically dowload updates and prompt you to install them? Some other choice?

Comment: @Didier Everything set to be as automatic as possible. Updated question with a screenshot.

Comment: OK, so UNCHECK all the boxes in the Advanced window, reboot your machine, go back to Software Update, check all the boxes again, reboot again, and you'll see that either the update badge is gone (no updates pending) or that updates are being downloaded and installed. AFAIK, you're running the latest stable version of macOS, but if you're subscribed to some Flight Test program, or if updates are available other than a newer version, they'll install then.

Comment: @Didier Alas, what happened when I did that was option 3: absolutely no change. The badge is still there, but it still says I’m up to date. I’m not subscribed to any Flight Test or beta release programmes (that I know of).

Comment: OK, try this: Open Terminal (in Applications/Utilities, if you haven't already pinned it to your Dock...), type or copy-paste the following command: "softwareupdate -l" (no quotes, and that’s a lowercase “L” and not the number one) then press Enter. If updates are listed as available, type or copy-paste "sudo softwareupdate -i -a" (no quotes) and press Enter. This will automatically install all pending updates, should there be any. You'll need to enter your admin password at the prompt. If it's your first use of Terminal, don't freak out when the cursor doesn't move as you type.

Comment: @Didier Nope, that just yields “No new software available”. I really do think I am fully up to date on everything (at least everything that goes through the macOS software update system), and this is more likely to be some sort of update status caching that needs to be flushed somewhere. I just don’t have the slightest idea where System Preferences takes its badge statuses from to check.

Comment: Well the, last resort, reboot in Safe Mode (keep the Shift key down upon restart until you reach your login screen), log in to your user account, wait a couple minutes for all system processes to catch their bearings, and reboot normally. This should do it...

Comment: @Didier Alas – the badge stubbornly remains after doing that! :-/

Comment: There are a few more commands you can try (here: https://www.macworld.com/article/3447396/how-to-stop-getting-a-reminder-to-update-to-catalina-in-macos.html) to tell macOS to temporarily ignore any software updates on your machine. The last command, near the bottom of the page, will put Software Update back in business. EDIT: you can also copy the following file to your Desktop, or Documents, and delete it from its original location: /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist . Next time you run Software Update, a new .plist file will be created, hopefully without the same glitch.

Comment: @Didier Well, that got me _somewhere_, at least: `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 0; killall Dock` makes the badge go away in the Dock and the main screen in System Preferences. As soon as I open the Software Update section, though, it comes right back (even though it still says no available updates). Removing/recreating `com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist` had no effect (in it, `LastUpdatesAvailable` is 0, as expected).

Comment: Bugger. It lasted for a while, but then it came back the next time (I presume) Software Update did a background check for updates. :-/

Comment: You have to return to Software Update / Advanced and uncheck "Check for updates", then remove the .plist file completely (Software Update will create a new, clean one when you next launch it), then do another "defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 0; killall Dock", preferably under sudo, but that's not mandatory. EDIT: can you open the .plist file (any text editor will do) and post a screenshot as edit of your question?

Comment: @Didier I’ve added in the contents of the .plist file. [a moment later] Huh – how bizarre! I just deactivated “Automatically keep my Mac up to date” and unchecked the “Check for updates” advanced option (instead of only unchecking the advanced options) and then reactivated “Automatically keep my Mac up to date” – and lo and behold, the badge is gone! Even when I close and reopen System Preferences/Software Update, it remains gone. Hallelujah!

Comment: Hey, fingers crossed! Keep us posted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check/uncheck automatic software updates in system preferences, then go to the advanced panel and just click OK. Worked for me.

Comment: That’s what appears to have done the trick for me as well – hasn’t come back yet, and it’s been six hours now, so fingers crossed.

Comment: I forgot to come back to this, but the badge never did come back. (I’ve since needed to update to Catalina anyway, so it’s moot now for my purposes.)

Answer (score 2):

The other tips didn't work for me in the beginning, but this exact sequence did, hope this will provide some additional clarification:

1. Uncheck "Automatically keep my Mac up to date"
2. In "Advanced..." uncheck "Check for updates"... OK
3. Close the System Preferences Panel (this step is important)
4. Re-Open System Preferences, you will notice that the badge has disappeared from the Dock icon
5. Check "Automatically keep my Mac up to date"

Comment: It appears it was the “Automatically keep my Mac up to date” option itself that did it – the advanced options alone aren’t enough, but toggling the entire auto-update system does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MacOS Catalina 10.15.4, follow the steps below:

1. Open Terminal and run the following commands one by one:

   ```
   defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs; killall Dock
   defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences DidShowPrefBundleIDs; killall Dock
   rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
   rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.plist
   sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
   sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.plist
   ```
2. Reboot to safe mode by following steps in [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201262).
3. Check for updates by going to

   > Apple icon -> System Preferences -> Software Update
4. Reboot to normal mode

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a variant of AdNauseum's answer. I did not have "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" checked, only under Advanced did I have "Check for updates" and "Download if updates are available" checked.

What eventually solved it for me, without doing reboots, was like this:

1. Open "System Preferences", "Software Updates" panel,
2. In "Advanced..." uncheck "Check for updates",
3. Close "System Preferences" window.
4. Re-Open "System Preferences" (for me, it still showed the badge)
5. Open "Software Updates" panel,
6. In "Advanced..." re-check "Check for updates",
7. Close "System Preferences" window.

Then, repeat steps 1..7 and then it should then be gone for good.

[MacOS sometimes behaves like Windows did a few decades ago. Go figure. :-)]